# Why do lifetimes differ when a function is called in a closure vs. being called directly in Rust?

Tags: rust

In the following code example:

```
fn default_values() -> &'static [u32] {
    static VALUES: [u32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
    &VALUES
}

fn main() {
    let values: [u32; 3] = [4, 5, 6];
    let optional_values: Option<&[u32]> = Some(&values);

    // this compiles and runs fine 
    let _v = optional_values.unwrap_or_else(|| default_values());

    // this fails to compile
    let _v = optional_values.unwrap_or_else(default_values);
}
```

the last statement fails to compile with:

```
error[E0597]: `values` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:49
   |
8  |     let optional_values: Option<&[u32]> = Some(&values);
   |                                                 ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
12 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I'm wondering:

1. what's happening that causes the difference in behaviour between the last two statements
2. whether the first `unwrap_or_else(|| default_values())` is the correct way of handling this, or whether there's a better pattern

Comment: I don't understand why but I changed it to `default_values as fn() -> &'static _` then it'll work.

Comment: Nightly + `feature(nll)` gives an additional information: *'borrowed value does not live long enough, cast requires that `values` is borrowed for `'static`'*

Comment: Look like the compile infer `_v` based on the return type of the function instead of infer `_v` based on the type of `optional_value`, and actually only `as fn() -> _` is enough. That simply a case of "you need to help the compiler".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `default_values` implements `Fn() -> &'static [u32]`, but not `for<'a> Fn() -> &'a [u32]`. Traits are [invariant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html), so you can't coerce "something that implements `Fn() -> &'static [u32]`" to "something that implements `Fn() -> &'a [u32]`" (for some `'a` smaller than `'static`), even though, logically speaking, `default_values` could satisfy both.

When it's called in a closure, `default_values()` returns a `&'static [u32]`, but it can be coerced immediately to a `&'a u32`, making the closure itself able to implement `Fn() -> &'a [u32]` (where the `&'a` is determined by the compiler).

As for why adding `as fn() -> &'static [u32]` works, I assume the compiler can recognize that the function pointer type `fn() -> &'static [u32]` is capable of implementing `Fn() -> &'a [u32]` for any `'a`. I'm not sure why it doesn't also do this for ordinary functions and closures; perhaps a future compiler version could be smart enough to allow the original code.

Another solution is to make the type of `default_values` one that can implement the `Fn` trait you need:

```
fn default_values<'a>() -> &'a [u32] {
    static VALUES: [u32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
    &VALUES
}
```

Instead of saying "this is a function that returns a `'static` reference", the signature here says "this is a function that can return a reference of any lifetime". We know that "a reference of any lifetime" has to be a `'static` reference, but the compiler sees the signatures as different because this one has an additional degree of freedom. [This change is sufficient to make your original example compile.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=96102b33624e739194569248cc7f12a3)

Comment: This still feels like a bug. Probably this is an unpolished edge of HRTB.

Comment: I agree, it does feel like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between a closure and a direct function call: It is just a matter of type inference.

closure that compiles:

```
let _v = optional_values.unwrap_or_else(|| default_values());
let _v = optional_values.unwrap_or_else(|| -> & [u32] {default_values()});
```

closure that not compiles:

```
let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, || -> &'static [u32] {default_values()});
```

function that compiles:

```
let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, default_values as fn() -> &'static _);
```

function that not compiles:

```
let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, default_values);
```

### A litte bit of explanation

Consider this equivalent code:

```
fn default_values() -> &'static [u32] {
    static VALUES: [u32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
    &VALUES
}

fn unwrap_or_else<T, F>(slf: Option<T>, f: F) -> T where
    F: FnOnce() -> T, {
        match slf {
            Some(t) => t,
            None => f()
        }
    }
```

the following snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let values: [u32; 3] = [4, 5, 6];
    let optional_values: Option<&[u32]> = Some(&values);

    let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, || -> &'static [u32] {default_values});

    // the above throws the same error of:
    //let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, default_values);
}
```

fails:

```
error[E0597]: `values` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:48
   |
18 |     let optional_values: Option<&[u32]> = Some(&values);
   |                                                ^^^^^^^
   |                                                |
   |                                                borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                                cast requires that `values` is borrowed for `'static`
...
27 | }
   | - `values` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Look from the monomorphization side: assuming that
the compiler infers that `T` resolves to the concrete type `&'static [u32]`,
and supposing that the produced code is something like:

```
fn unwrap_or_else_u32_sl_fn_u32_sl(slf: Option<&'static [u32]>,
                                   f: fn() -> &'static [u32]) -> &'static [u32] {
    ...
}
```

then the above monomorphization explains the error:

`slf` value is `optional_values`: an `Option<&'a [u32]>` that does not live enough and clearly cannot be cast because it does not satisfies the `'static` lifetime requirement.

If you write:

```
let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, || default_values());

// the same, expliciting the return type:
let _v = unwrap_or_else(optional_values, || -> & [u32] {default_values()});
```

It compiles: now the lifetime of the return type is compatible with the `optional_values` lifetime.

Finally, I'm not able to explain why, but the evidence shows that the cast `as fn() -> &'static _` helps the compiler to be sure that decoupling lifetimes bound to `optional_values` and `default_values` is safe.